# Windows Debugger engine api to get heap allocation info of an address

Tags: debugging, windbg

Im writing an extension command that simulates !Heap -x address. I need to get the heap allocation info for an input address.

Right now I run !heap -p -a and parse the output. But in recent versions of Debugger the command is hanging. I can use !heap -x but I don't want to be dependent on heap commands if possible.

Are there any Debugger engine APIs that provide this info.?

Answer (score 0):

no afaik all the heap parsing logic is embedded inside ext!heap and exts!*heap* functions as below
i dont think dbgeng exposes any heap apis

```
exts!ScanProcessHeaps+0x99:
00007ffc`5f856fad e852a2fdff      call    exts!GetFieldData (00007ffc`5f831204)
0:000>
exts!ScanProcessHeaps+0xc3:
00007ffc`5f856fd7 e828a2fdff      call    exts!GetFieldData (00007ffc`5f831204)
0:000>
exts!ScanProcessHeaps+0x103:
00007ffc`5f857017 ff155b080300    call    qword ptr [exts!_imp_malloc (00007ffc`5f887878)] ds:00007ffc`5f887878={msvcrt!malloc (00007ffc`70969d30)}
0:000>
exts!ScanProcessHeaps+0x12d:
00007ffc`5f857041 e8b209feff      call    exts!HeapExtReadPointer (00007ffc`5f8379f8)
0:000>
exts!ScanProcessHeaps+0x12d:
00007ffc`5f857041 e8b209feff      call    exts!HeapExtReadPointer (00007ffc`5f8379f8)
0:000>
exts!ScanProcessHeaps+0x175:
00007ffc`5f857089 e83e570200      call    exts!IsSegmentHeap (00007ffc`5f87c7cc)
0:000>
exts!ScanProcessHeaps+0x188:
00007ffc`5f85709c e8ebf7ffff      call    exts!ReadHeapData (00007ffc`5f85688c)
0:000>
exts!ScanProcessHeaps+0x175:
00007ffc`5f857089 e83e570200      call    exts!IsSegmentHeap (00007ffc`5f87c7cc)
0:000>
exts!ScanProcessHeaps+0x188:
00007ffc`5f85709c e8ebf7ffff      call    exts!ReadHeapData (00007ffc`5f85688c)
0:000>
```

your specific !heap -x -v logic is inside

```
    exts!heap+0x1c5:
    00007ffc`5f8333e5 e802690200      call    exts!HeapFindBlock (00007ffc`5f859cec)
and 
0:000>
exts!HeapFindBlock+0x126:
00007ffc`5f859e12 e81dfcffff      call    exts!SearchVMReference (00007ffc`5f859a34)
0:000>
```

basically it is all undocumented it doesn't even use winapis like HeapWalk() and Heap32First() functions or RtlpQueryDebugInformation() functions

[Some Reading Material can be found here](https://securityxploded.com/enumheaps.php)